# возможна ли одна БД для сайта и приложения?

Tags: android, база-данных, ios, веб-программирование

Разрабатываю сайт одновременно начал делать приложение на андроид и в дальнейшем будет приложение на ios.

возможно ли создать БД, так чтоб и сайт и оба приложения могли быть подключены к нему, читали и записывали данные.

Comment: Фактически да, ты же можешь написать на сайте API для работы приложений с бд.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Так как вы собираетесь создавать приложения под **разные** устройства, а именно под **разные** операционные систему - вам придется писать два разных приложения, но главное, что логика и суть приложений **остается одинаковой**. Базу конечно, желательно использовать одну, потому что использовать две, для двух (по сути одинаковых приложений, просто написанных на двух разных языках) будет достаточно *проблематично синхронизировать*. В вашем случае создание стороннего, независимого сервиса API (называйте как хотите) будет одним из лучших решением.
Вкратце ваш API будет работать по принципу (request\response) - запрос\ответ. Это позволит вам создать один сервис (API), который к примеру будет написан на php и он не будет знать какие приложения к нему обращаются, он будет принимать запрос, и отправлять ответ.

Благодаря созданию API, ваших приложений может быть **сколько угодно** - они все будут общаться **через созданный вами сервис**, *совершенно не зная* друг о друге.

Могу порекомендовать к прочтению [данную статью](https://habr.com/ru/post/351890/), несущую полезную информацию об вашем вопросе.